# Why am I getting incorrect results via DC test performed in Matlab/Simulink?

Tags: induction-motor, matlab, simulink

I am performing DC test in Simulink to find the stator resistance.
The three phase SCIM parameters are taken as:

[image: Parameters]

The setup in the Simulink is shown below:
[image: Simulink Setup]

The %error is too much (25%).
Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong?

Edit: when I changed the value of gain from 1/2 to 2/3(which should be in case of delta connection) I am getting the correct results what is happening?

Comment: Why 1/sqrt(3) ?

Comment: Even after replacing 1/2 with 1/sqrt(3) the percentage error is 13.4%

Comment: I would expect the given parameters to be line-to-neutral values. That is what would be used for the equivalent circuit. The rotor value is the value referred to the stator, but that would not enter into the test.

Comment: You appear to be applying 12 volts across the combination of the B and C windings in parallel with each other, with that parallel combination connected in series with the A winding.

Comment: @CharlesCowie But when I performed blocked rotor test and the no load test the values of the rotor's impedance were that of referred to the stator side.

Comment: The NL & BR tests are AC tests. The motor is a transformer. With AC, the rotor values are connected to the stator through the transformer ratio. With the DC tests, the rotor is, in effect, disconnected.

Comment: @CharlesCowie Ok I get it. But the DC test is independent of rotor's impedance and the mutual inductance so how will that matter?

Comment: How does what matter? The DC test provides a value for the stator resistance. The purpose for performing the tests is to determine the equivalent circuit component values and the losses.

Comment: @CharlesCowie You said that in DC test the rotor's values are not referred to the stator side but to the line-to-neutral. My point is that in DC test only the stator's resistance is limiting the current flow so how does the rotor's value matter?

Comment: There is a new edit in question!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version of the equivalent circuit of an induction motor is the most complete version that is commonly used. You can see that when a DC voltage is applied between L and N, all of the inductors become short circuits and what is left is simply Rs and the DC source. The transformer and the components in the secondary circuit essentially disappear.

[image]
Diagram adapted from Malcom Barnes "Practical Variable Speed Drives and Power Electronics"

In the simulation, I would expect the same, except that there is Rsa, Rsb and Rsc connected as shown below. The resistance of the connected combination of three resistors would be 1.5 times an individual resistor value, so the multiplier in the simulation, must be 2/3.
[image]

The resistance test can be performed by connecting to two terminals with no connection to the third terminal. Note that you can not determine the true resistance unless you know whether the motor is connected wye or delta. If you don't know the connection, assume wye. The equivalent circuit is based on the wye connection, so the wye equivalent is used for analysis regardless of the actual connection. IEEE Std 112-2017 specifies measuring the terminal to terminal resistance.

Comment: so If I will connect a very high load in C phase of the motor, the  gain would be of 0.5 right?

Comment: Yes. The C phase can be connected through a high resistance or left open. The only description that I have at hand shows the test performed by connecting to only two motor terminals. See paragraph added to answer.